# Please do not break IE8 unless it is really for good

Tags: support, browser-support

I know IE8 is officially unsupported.

I keep that in mind and I accept that when new actual features are rolled out on Stack Overflow, IE8 might end up unable to use them. I'm happy with that. E.g. I can't search for Stack Exchange sites by typing into that "More Stack Exchange Communities" textbox in The Dropdown when I have to use IE8, it just doesn't work. That is fine and not a problem.

However, may I suggest please, that in cases when IE8 is severely broken simply because of one little ([optionally stupid](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167440/147640)) bit of JavaScript that happens to use an unsupported property without really meaning it, a support request for fixing this could be allowed to exist?

There are many environments (companies) where people are stuck with IE8. According to Wikipedia, the [IE8 market share is 21.25%](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE8#Adoption) as of June 2014, which is a lot.

Currently stub.js is broken for IE8 because of `textContent` property that does not exist (`text` property does). This means there is no editing toolbar, the editing hotkeys do not work, and the question/answer preview does not appear.

Comment: Out of interest, why are you still using IE8? Arbitrary limitation imposed by network administrators?

Comment: @JonK many companies using still IE8

Comment: @JonK I actually have many computers in multiple offices. In some places it's because I can't install any IE version I might fancy (which might be a [sensible restriction](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808279)), in some other places I need IE8 for development/support purposes, in some other places my workflow involves advanced use of the search providers, and that bit is broken since IE9 due to the united url-search box, so I'm stuck with IE8 even though I'd love the rendering engine of IEnew.

Comment: Do you really need to use the same browser for testing as browsing Stack Overflow? (Also, the 21.25% figure isn’t representative of programmers, or even “people who would use Stack Exchange”).

Comment: @Sirl33tname I have to use IE9 on my workstation in the office, but I *only* use that for testing purposes. I have Firefox/Chrome installed for actual browsing, and I would have to seriously question any administrator that refused to allow more secure, more up-to-date browsers to be installed on the machines on their network.

Comment: [This site claims 10% usage worldwide.](http://theie8countdown.com/)  While I'm not sure which statistics to believe, why would it be so terrible to switch to a supported browser (Firefox, Chrome) and use Stack Overflow on that?

Comment: [You may want to double check the source of your statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_Applications#Criticism)

Comment: Of course keeping IE8 compatability is a good idea? A really good idea!?! Why did anyone actually downvote this?

@minitech My company has over 2k software engineers and we have lots of old technology. We will migrate to IE10 in a year or so. . . 
Turning off compatability for IE8 would remove a lot of programmers 1-2k maybe.

Comment: @User123456789 Why are you being forced to use an old out-of-support browser for anything other than absolutely necessary product testing? If you are, then a serious conversation needs to take place with the system administrator(s), and if you aren't...well I don't know any programmers that would *choose* to use IE8 over Firefox or Chrome. IE8 needs to be killed with fire, not supported "until everyone has upgraded". They'll never upgrade if that happens.

Comment: Does StackOverflow has a list of supported browsers (i.e. browsers they actually test the site in)? Anyway, IE8 in 2014, seriously? It was discontinued in 2010 and long term support ended last April together with Windows XP... Why should StackOverflow support something that is unsupported by its own vendor? Also, given the technical audience of the site, those stats might not be significant.

Comment: Well... "unsupported" means "unsupported". As in, "we won't do anything specifically for it, we don't care if it breaks". Asking SE to care for IE8 when they have explicitly stated that they won't seems somewhat pointless. If anything, you should start convincing SE that this non-support policy is a bad move on their part for reasons of X, Y and Z and needs to be changed.

Comment: @JonK OK so this is no longer about why SO should be IE8 compatible but why do we still use old browers. 

Lets give some perspective. I work for a large non-software company. We have huge amounts of custom in house web portal tools for in house employees not the general public. So our users are our employees and they are all in <IE8 ~160,000 users. The software works now, and is a massive cost to upgrade thousands of applications for no benefit? So why would you? We have a lot of users in older versions of IE even! Can you estimate the cost on this? Its a lot of developer time per product. .

Comment: @User123456789 I'm required to use IE for some in-house things at my company too. That doesn't mean I use IE for anything else... No benefit though? Call me crazy but surely the fact that you'd be using a supported browser that is still recieving *security updates and fixes* would be a significant benefit when the alternative is using an old, out-of-support browser where any security holes are left open? There's no much to say about whether SO should consider being IE8 compatible or not: it shouldn't.

Comment: @JonK Lots of programmers are using IE at work. Most users dont have that issue and so they wont care. I don't have that issue either but if it would affect a large number of users and thus is a good idea to keep it working.

Comment: Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers and one source has IE at 58.38% usage and another has it at 19.0% (and I have seen sites that have even lower IE usage numbers) usage. So you really need to take any usage stat with a grain of salt and realize that the numbers they give will depend on what type of sites they get their information from. All that really matter are the usage numbers for each individual site and what they want to support.

Answer (score 6):

I see three possible situations:

- You're a developer and you need IE8 for testing. You should have another, more recent browser installed for all your other needs. Preferably you should be running that IE8 in a VM as to avoid polluting your environment.
- You're a regular user, you need IE8 for an in-house application and you need access to the SE network for work related purposes. You should be able to convince your manager or system administrator to give you access to another, more recent browser for all your other needs.
- You're a regular user, you need IE8 for an in-house application and you do not need access to the SE network for work related purposes. You probably have no business visiting the network during your working hours then.

Supporting IE8, a browser that was RTM more than 5 years ago, takes a lot of time (talking from experience) that often isn't worth it. The only legitimate reason I can see is when it is in the interest of your business to support it, for example if you'd miss out on a significant amount of revenue.